# Floating three divs next to a fourth one

Tags: html, css, css-float

Is there a way I can have a 2 column layout, with div one, two and three on the left and div four on the right? I could achieve this by adding another div around divs one, two and three, but can it be done without adding any html?

Comment: "div one, two and three on the left and div three on the right" seems to imply that div three is both on the left and the right. ?

Comment: Sorry, I meant four on the right. Ive updated my question. Thanks

Comment: do you want this way : http://jsfiddle.net/kMvbw/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/hwpJT/

put `#four` above others and add `float:right`

Comment: So just to check, If I wanted #four to be after the others then I would need to add a div around #one, #two and #three? Thanks

Comment: if you want to keep that html structure (#four after others) then u'll need to do that particular hack.. no other ways to achieve that result afaik :)

Comment: wait, there is a way to achieve that behaviour, keeping that html and hacking with css => http://jsfiddle.net/steweb/hwpJT/1/ (just set container's position to relative and set #four's position to absolute and top and right to 0)